# What is the relationship between robustness to Adversarial Attacks and Out-Of-Distribution OOD generalization?

Tags: machine-learning

You hear the word Robustness (defined as a model's robustness to spurious correlations ) a lot associated with Adversarial-Attacks and OOD Generalization and wonder how are these concepts interrelated?!

Answer (score 0):

Well, to begin, Facebook addressed the problem of Robustness in their package Captum in the tutorial titled "Captum Robustness with Image Classification" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkA8H.png). In the Facebook, tutorial Robustness is treated in the context of "Resilience to Adversarial Attacks" where a model performance must stay consistent under Adverserial-Attacks much like stress-testing in the reliability engineering science.

Also, Google addressed Robustness in the Colab Notebook demo of their new state-of-the-art pre-trained image classifier Vit-Pixel [2]. Google much like Facebook addressed Robustness as shown in the image below as "Resilience to Adversarial Attacks" applied in the form of Gaussian Noise. Actually, Facebook even used "Gaussian blur" as one Adversarial Attack type in their tutorial [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkA8H.png). Furthermore, Google as you can see in the image claims that a resilient model to Adverserial-Attacks is also robust to Covariate-Shifted data. Whereas, Google in their blog post introducing Vit-Pixel defines Covariate-Shifted data under the category of "Out-Of-Distribution" Generalization [3].

All in all, a resilient model to Adversarial Attacks is resilient to Co-variate Shifted data and thus should have a high "Out-Of-Distribution" Generalization performance. "Out-Of-Distribution" Generalization is also defined as "Domain Generalization" by Facebook in [4] and is measured by a model's (image classifier in this context) predictive performance on the same class but from a different data source. With high OOD Generalization performance, the model can be trusted in production.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkA8H.png) https://captum.ai/tutorials/CIFAR_Captum_Robustness

[2] https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/uncertainty-baselines/blob/main/experimental/plex/plex_vit_demo.ipynb

[3] https://ai.googleblog.com/2022/07/towards-reliability-in-deep-learning.html

[4] https://github.com/facebookresearch/DomainBed